# Get random sentences from a set of text files

Tags: python, random, linguistics

I am not much of a programmer but have been asked to help a professor of mine with a research project which requires a basic level of programming knowledge. We are pulling 1000 sentences from a set of 22 text files. Each text file contains thousands of sentences, all strung together in one paragraph, like so:

```
By this time , the resistance was severe . Why ? Consider the houses that were coming down , to be replaced by modern flats . They are typical of the row houses for workers of the dreary industrial towns of England . These " cottages , " as they were called in Sunderland , were built for the working class by unnamed builders one hundred years ago . Many were rented , but most were by this time owned by their inhabitants . The houses sit directly on the sidewalk . There are no trees on the street . There is no front yard .
```

Pretty ugly. Anyway, I am unsure how to pull random sentences from a block of text like this. I am fairly confident that these are the steps my program must follow:

1. Select a random text file from the set of 22 text files.
2. Select a random sentence from the text file.

   - I think this could be done by choosing a random number and "counting" fullstops (.) up to that number, then choosing the sentence after that fullstop as the random sentence, stopping at the next fullstop.
3. Write the selected sentence to a separate textfile.
4. Repeat 999 more times.

Here is the code I have written so far. It does not "count" the fullstops as I considered doing above, because I don't know how to do that, but I tried to start outlining the basic pieces I know. I know my code is pretty ugly, but I have never really programmed anything before. Thanks for the help!

```
fileNumber = 0
sentenceNumber = 0
i = 0
fname = "x"
sentence = "x"

for i < 1000

    fileNumber = random.randint(0, 22)          #chooses a random number in order to assign one of the text files
    sentenceNumber = random.randint(0, NUMBER OF FULLSTOPS) #chooses a random number to select a random sentence from the previously selected text file

    if fileNumber == 0              #assigns the file to search based on the random number stored in fileNumber
        fname = "w_acad_1990.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 1
        fname = "w_acad_1991.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 2
        fname = "w_acad_1992.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 3
        fname = "w_acad_1993.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 4
        fname = "w_acad_1994.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 5
        fname = "w_acad_1995.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 6
        fname = "w_acad_1996.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 7
        fname = "w_acad_1997.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 8
        fname = "w_acad_1998.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 9
        fname = "w_acad_1999.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 10
        fname = "w_acad_2000.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 11
        fname = "w_acad_2001.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 12
        fname = "w_acad_2002.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 13
        fname = "w_acad_2003.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 14
        fname = "w_acad_2004.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 15
        fname = "w_acad_2005.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 16
        fname = "w_acad_2006.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 17
        fname = "w_acad_2007.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 18
        fname = "w_acad_2008.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 19
        fname = "w_acad_2009.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 20
        fname = "w_acad_2010.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 21
        fname = "w_acad_2011.txt"
    else if fileNumber == 22
        fname = "w_acad_2012.txt"
    else
        fname = "x" 

    #select a random sentence
    #write that sentence to a text file

    i++
```

Comment: You could `split()` your sentences on fullstops, which returns a list of sentences, and you can pull a random one from the list using `random.choice`

Comment: Do you have any memory restrictions? How big are all the text files combined? The easiest option would be to load in memory all files at once  and randomly choose as many sentences as you want.

Comment: @Reti43 This seems like a smart way to do this. I suppose my memory restrictions would be the 4 GB of memory on my laptop. All of the files are around 2.5 - 3 MB, so this shouldn't be a problem. Do you know of any tutorials on doing something like this, or have suggestions as to how to do something like this?

Comment: clemtoy has already provided such an approach. You'll notice though that he merges all sentences from all files into one single pool. If you want each sentence to have the same probability of being chosen, his way is fine. If you want each file to have uniform probability of being chosen, you'll want a list of lists.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, missed that! Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your data set, It might be necessary to take into account that sentences don't always end in '.' (e.g., '!' and '?') and a '.' might be following an abbreviation (e.g., 'Dr.' or 'e.g.').  If selecting random sentences is going to be done often, it might be worthwhile to combine all the files in to one file that has one sentence per line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest something like that:

```
import re
from random import sample

sentences = []
for i in range(23):
    with open('w_acad_{}.txt'.format(i)) as f:
        sentences += re.findall(r".*?[\.\!\?]+", f.read())

selected = sample(sentences, 1000)
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(selected))
```

First of all, if you choose the file before the sentence, there is not equiprobability between all sentences. It's better to retrieve all the sentences before to choose.

Do not open the file 1000 times. It's very heavy!

Do not use `split` as suggested by others because you'll lose the delimiters.
Here I use `findall` from `re` module so that I can use several delimiters (not only `.` but also `!` etc.) and I keep it when I retrieve the sentences.

Finally, you can use `sample` from `random` module to select 1000 sentences.

Comment: Wow, this worked fabulously! Thank you so much! Any idea how I could have each sentence in the "out.txt" file appear on its own line? I tried concantenating a "\n" on the last line like so: f.write(''.join(selected + "\n")) but that produces an error.

Comment: Try `'\n'.join(selected)`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: @K.Swan You're welcome. You should consider to improve the regex of the `findall` function (see @RootTwo comment)

Comment: Thanks for the code clemtoy. Here is a modification that takes a string and returns the removed sentence, and the remaining text (if the string has more than one sentence)
def remove_random_sentence(txt):
    sentences = []
    sentences += re.findall(r".*?[\.\!\?]+", txt)
    if len(sentences) > 1:
        removed_sentence = sample(sentences, 1)[0]  # sample returns list, accsess first element to get string
        return txt.replace(removed_sentence, ''), removed_sentence
    else:
        return 'ONLY ONE SENTENCE', 'REMOVE'

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

# Do this 1000 times:
for i in range(1000):
    fileNumber = random.randint(0,22)
    # calculate file name instead of long condition chain:
    with open("w_acad_{}.txt".format(1990+fileNumber)) as f:
        # read file and split sentences on full stop:
        sentences = f.read().split(".")
    with open("sentence_{}.txt".format(i), "w") as f:
        # write a random sentence from the file:
        f.write(random.choice(sentences) + ".")
```

Comment: It's very inefficient to read the file once for each sentence.  You should read it just once before the loop.  Also, you will want to remove each line that you take from the list.

Comment: Won't `sentences` be gone/out of scope by the time you reach the second `with open()`?

Comment: @zondo The way the random selection was described in the question, I can't remove the sentence after I chose it. Inefficient? Yes, but since this is the way the randomization is supposed to happen apparently, the only other way would be to read in all files at once (which might be too big to fit in memory).

Comment: @jDo No, not all blocks make scopes.

Comment: @L3viathan *"No, not all blocks make scopes."* no, maybe not but I would still expect a `NameError` or something like that. Also, doesn't `randint()` need a lower bound? Is it implicit in python3 or something? (I haven't seen any indication that OP is using python3 but that could explain why it looks a little weird to me)

Comment: This may be a reasonable solution but it biases selection to sentences in smaller files. Suppose file 10 has 4 times as many sentences as file 3 yet they are both selected equally. File 3 sentences will be used 4 times as often as they should.

Comment: @tdelaney What about making the number of words to pick per file a percentage of the total number of words in the file?

Comment: @L3viathan I don't know if you misunderstood me or something, but this is what I meant. Python3: `NameError: name 'sentences' is not defined` and `TypeError: randint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'`.
Python2: `TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)` and `NameError: name 'sentences'` is not defined

Comment: @jDo After fixing the `randint` problem I did not get your `sentences` problem. Not surprising because `sentences` is created in the local function scope and doesn't loose visibility just because the `with` statement ends. Something like that happening would make `with` statements far less useful

Comment: @tdelay Ok, it might be because I wasn't able to open the file since it didn't exist. That threw an exception and, naturally, anything following the first `with` would not have been executed. The reason why I would *expect* `sentences` to not be defined is simply because I assume that anything on the same indentation level does not have access to other "things" on that level. Eg. I would typically nest the second `with open` within the first `with open` if I wanted access to the first from within the second.

Comment: @tdelaney Yep, you're right regarding `with`. Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful for anyone else: Here is a modification that removes a sentence from `txt` and returns the remaining text and the removed sentence,

```
def remove_random_sentence(txt):
    sentences = []
    sentences += re.findall(r".*?[\.\!\?]+", txt)
    if len(sentences) > 1:
        removed_sentence = sample(sentences, 1)[0]  # sample returns list, accsess first element to get string
        return txt.replace(removed_sentence, ''), removed_sentence
    else:
        return 'ONLY ONE SENTENCE', 'REMOVE'
```